# Marking build success based on exit code

Tags: teamcity, testcomplete

I use TeamCity to que and report my TestComplete UI tests.

When the exit code in TestComplete is greater than 0 - it marks the build as a failure.

Exit codes for reference: https://support.smartbear.com/testexecute/docs/running/automating/command-line/exit-codes.html

Ideally I want an exit code of 1 to be marked as a warning in TeamCity - alternatively I would be happy to mark it as successful when it's an exit code 1. If it's any other exit code I'm happy to leave it as an unsuccessful "Build"

Answer (score 1):

You can create a small command-line utility (or CMD/PowerShell script) that will run TestComplete using the parameters passed to the application itself and return exit codes as you want. Use this utility to run your tests instead of running TestComplete directly.